# Why does monkeypatching os.path require a path argument?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

pytest has this example in the [monkeypatching](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) docs:

```
import os.path
def getssh(): # pseudo application code
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~admin"), '.ssh')

def test_mytest(monkeypatch):
    def mockreturn(path):
        return '/abc'
    monkeypatch.setattr(os.path, 'expanduser', mockreturn)
    x = getssh()
    assert x == '/abc/.ssh'
```

When I remove the `path` argument from the `mockreturn` function, I get the error

```
    def getssh():  # pseudo application code
>       return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~admin"), '.ssh')
E       TypeError: mockreturn() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I don't understand what is providing that positional argument?

Also, when I reimplement the same thing for pathlib.Path.home() I cannot have this argument `path` there, otherwise it won't work. Unfortunately, the documentation does not say anything about that ominous `path` argument.

Any illumination for what magic is happening here would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to replace `os.path.expanduser` that takes one argument with a mock that doesn't take arguments at all which results to an error when called. 
Under the hood `monkeypatch.setattr` uses builtin [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) so the original version is basically doing following which works since both `expanduser` and `mock` take single argument:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> def mock(path):
...     return '/abc'
... 
>>> setattr(os.path, 'expanduser', mock)
>>> os.path.expanduser('~admin')
'/abc'
```

Now if you try to replace `expanduser` with a method that doesn't take arguments and keep calling it the same way you'll get an error:

```
>>> setattr(os.path, 'expanduser', mock)
>>> os.path.expanduser('~admin')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: mock() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Note that you'll get exactly the same error if you try to call `mock` directly:

```
>>> mock('~admin')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: mock() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't click/see that `expanduser` is of course the function that provides the path, while pathlib.Path.home() works without it.